# A verb following another verb

Tags: verbs

> We'll see how much they can do come the postseason.

In this sentence, is the word 'come' used as an infinitive or a past participle? At least it makes sense to me it is a past participle, but how come it is grammatically explained if it is an infinitive?

Answer (score 1):

*Come* can be a preposition: [[1]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come), [[2]](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/come_2).

> You can use *come* before a date, time, or event to mean when that date, time, or event arrives. For example, you can say *come the spring* to mean 'when the spring arrives'.
>
> *Come the election on the 20th of May, we will have to decide.
>
>   He's going to be up there again come Sunday.*
>
> ---
>
> when the time mentioned comes
>
> *They would have been married forty years come this June.
>
>   Come next week she’ll have changed her mind.*

Therefore, your sentence can be paraphrased as:

> We'll see how much they can do **when the postseason comes**.